# How to give corner radius in WebView in react native

Tags: react-native

I have added a View as a container of Webview and then added `corderRadius` but not worked

```
<View
        flex={1}
        borderTopLeftRadius={12}
        borderTopRightRadius={12}
      >
        <WebView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
    />
</View>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution for this, just add `overflow: "hidden"` in the parent view

```
  <View
    style={{
      overflow: "hidden",
      flex: 1,
      borderTopLeftRadius: 12,
      borderTopRightRadius: 12,
    }}
  >
    <WebView style={{ flex: 1 }} />
  </View>
```